# Can Negative Predictive Value and Positive Predictive Values be the same?

Tags: neural-networks, predictive-models, metric

Is there any scenario where a negative predictive value and a positive predictive value would be the same? Specifically, when using a neural network for binary prediction. Can this be a sign of overfitting or underfitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PPV and NPV can certainly be the same, although there is generally no *a priori* reason to expect they would be so.

$$PPV = \frac{\text{Number true positive predictions}}{\text{Number positive predictions}}$$

$$NPV = \frac{\text{Number true negative predictions}}{\text{Number negative predictions}}$$

Because PPV and NPV are conditional on the prevalence of the category being tested (e.g., PPV decreases and NPV increases as prevalence of the category decreases), for any classifier's sensitivity and specificity (assuming they are less than perfect), there is some prevalence for which $PPV = NPV$.